# How to determine 32bit vs 64bit Windows at software installation time

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to write a script that will install one of 6 different `.MSI` files depending on details of the system.  I don't know how to tell the difference between a 32-bit and a 64-bit Windows installation, so that I can install the 64-bit `.MSI` on 64-bit systems and the 32-bit `.MSI` on 32-bit systems.  The script is in Python, if that matters.

Comment: Isn't this a thing you can do from inside the .MSI itself?

Comment: Ok so the script runs but I only have 64 bit I have no idea how to script so it runs either 64 bit vs 32 bit depending on what system I run it on.

Comment: I also have a .exe that needs the same I just need some ideas.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx looks relevant for your `.exe` (note especially the "tested and working visual C++ code" in the comments").  Also, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922259/how-to-implement-single-installer-for-32-64-platforms it is *not* possible to do this from inside the `.msi`, bah humbug.

Comment: You could execute `wmic OS get OSArchitecture` to get the info.  I'm not sure how far back this is supported though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
# ('64bit', 'ELF')
```

or

```
import os
is64 = os.environ.get("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432") == 'AMD64' or \
       os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"] != 'x86'
```

Comment: That'll detect a 64-bit Python interpreter, but it'll be wrong if you're running the 32-bit Python interpreter on 64-bit Windows, won't it?

Comment: My question is how should I create an installer that chooses which MSI to install based off of the target machine's processor?

Comment: My script will run and if it detects 64bit installer on a 32bit system it fails.

Comment: @user3597409, added a new method

Comment: Isn't `os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]` equivalent to your second method?

Comment: What about my 32bit MSI?

Comment: @user3597409, I think it would be x86, according to [msft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx). but I've not tested it.

Comment: The `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable should be set to `x86` for WOW64 processes.  However, the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` environment variable will be set to `AMD64` so this should be a reasonably reliable test.  (This environment variable will not exist for 64-bit processes, so if you might be running in a 64-bit interpreter you'll need to check that first.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an [MSI or EXE wrapper that will install the package one by one](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html).
The tutorial I linked explains how to do this very easy with Advanced Installer, not scripting is required as you have GUI options to configure each installer, so it is much easy to maintain.

Advanced Installer allows you to select from a tree on which OS you want to run each package, so you can specify to run only on x64 or x86 machines, or on just a particular set of x64 or x86 machines.
[image: Install Conditions in Advanced Installer]

You do need however a Professional license to the tool, but you can try it for 30 days, to see if it saves you enough time to make it worth the migration, as it should do.

Comment: Does this run silently?

Comment: yes it does, also you can pass different command lines for your packages, so for example if the main package runs silently they run silent too, and if the main package runs with full UI they could have a different command line

Answer (score 0):

The best way is.

```
is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
```

Comment: That'll detect a 64-bit Python interpreter, but it'll be wrong if you're running the 32-bit Python interpreter on 64-bit Windows, won't it?

Comment: Will this logic say hey if the installer is 64 bit install. If not run the 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

The following registry entry will show you whether the system is 32bit or 64bit,

**Key Path:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0

**Value Name:** Platform ID

**Value Type:** REG_DWORD

For 32bit,

**Value Data (in Hex.):** 1

For 64bit,

**Value Data (in Hex.):** 2