# How to create setup file with many dependencies?

Tags: wpf, installation

I have a WPF project (app1.exe). In order to run app1.exe, user needs to run a few exe files and msi files (e.g. .NET 4.0, speech platform, etc.) to install some libraries before running WPF exe file. Therefore, I want to ask a few things:

1. How to create setup file for WPF project?
2. How to automatically install dependencies (with specific order) before running setup.exe?
3. How to automatically decide x86 or x64 files to install?

Comment: You can try [WixSharp](https://wixsharp.codeplex.com), it is well documented and has good examples, including installing dependencies. It is better to [separate install packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922259/how-to-implement-single-installer-for-32-64-platforms) for x86 or x64, but with WIX you can try to [automate it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147498/how-to-deploy-64-bit-and-a-32-bit-windows-installer-package-as-a-single-setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Installshield for Visual Studio and you can create a setup file.
2. Create a bat file and run those file before your setup.exe
3. Follow this template:

   @echo off

   if defined ProgramFiles(x86) (

   ```
   @echo yes
   @echo Some 64-bit work
   ```

   ) else (

   ```
   @echo no
   @echo Some 32-bit work
   ```

   )